# Keeping context while scrolling

Tags: scrolling

Suppose I have a very long file, for example:

```
class X {
    // ...
    void foo() {
        // ...
        if (something) {
            a00();
            a01();
            a02();
            // ...
            // ...
            a98();
            a99();
        }
    }
}
```

When scrolling down to the bottom, all the context (ie., `class X`, `void foo`, `if (something)`) is invisible simply because its outside the current view:

```
            a93();
            a94();
            a95();
            a96();
            a97();
            a98();
            a99();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make vim keep the current context, ie, display something like this:

```
class X {                    <C>
    void foo() {             <C>
        if (something) {     <C>
            a96();
            a97();
            a98();
            a99();
        }
    }
}
```

with some markings (`<C>` in my example) to denote that the lines above `a96` are not directly preceding the next one?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to do that is by making a new temporary window above the buffer which displays the lines you want. It's do-able, but some work.

Comment: I remember that there was some plugin that did this for C/C++, using window above (as @Carpetsmoker said), but that was long ago and now I'm not able to find it (or I ask google wrongly). Maybe someone here uses it or knows the name?

Comment: What about a fold expression to deal with that?

Comment: @lsrdg i think a fold would be the easiest way to do it...

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble but probably not as dinamic as needed... (:     But it would be interesting to have a smart fold that would 'fould up' while scrolling down. Right now, I would go with Carpetsmoker.

Comment: What's wrong with `1G3:sp<c-w>j`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply use `:rightbelow split`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for that [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=208). I've checked it and it works with Vim8, although plugin was written for Vim6. It opens a window above and updates it on CursorHold event. It's supposed to work only with C files, but adding line:

```
au CursorHold  *.[cC][pP][pP] call <SID>cursorhold()
```

right after line `431` makes it work with C++ files as well.

**EDIT**:
I've managed to update the script to include C++ classes (and it should work with Pike programming language f.ex. as well). I'll update it a bit more later on. Updated version can be found [here](https://github.com/grodzik/vim-ctx)